# django - Type Error __init__ positional argument

Tags: python, django, typeerror

I'm creating a blog by django, when I want to open **http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login** I get the error:

> **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Exception Location:

> C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\myDjanEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py
>   in _get_response, line 124

And this is the 124th line of the code from base.py:

```
if response is None:
    wrapped_callback = self.make_view_atomic(callback)
    try:
<!-- line 124 -->   response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
```

VIEWS.PY CODES:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404,redirect
from django.utils import timezone
from blog.models import Post,Comment
from blog.forms import PostForm,CommentForm
from django.urls import reverse,reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.generic import (TemplateView,ListView,
                                  DetailView,CreateView,
                                  UpdateView,DeleteView,)
# Create your views here.

class AboutView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'about.html'

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-published_date')

class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post

class CreatePostView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'
    # form_class = PostForm
    model = Post

class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'
    # form_class = PostForm
    model = Post

class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin,DeleteView):
    model = Post
    success_url = reverse_lazy('post_list')

class DraftListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'blog/post_list.html'
    model = Post

def get_queryset(self):
    return Post.objects.filter(published_date__isnull=True,).order_by('created_date')

###############################################
###############################################

@login_required
def post_publish(request,pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,pk=pk)
    post.publish
    return redirect('post_detail',pk=pk)



@login_required
def add_comment_to_post(request,pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('post_detail',pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request,'blog/comment_form.html',{'form':form})

@login_required
def comment_approve(request,pk):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment,pk=pk)
    comment.approve()
    return redirect('post_detail',pk=comment.post.pk)

@login_required
def comment_remove(request,pk):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment,pk=pk)
    post_pk = comment.post.pk
    comment.delete()
    return redirect('post_detail',pk=post_pk)
```

FORMS.PY CODES:

```
from django import forms
from blog.models import Post,Comment

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta():
        model = Post
        fields = ('author','title','text')

        widgets = {
            'title':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'textinputclass'}),
            'text':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'editable medium-editor-textarea postcontent'})
        }


class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta():
        model = Comment
        fields = ('author','text')

        widgets = {
            'author':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'textinputclass'}),
            'text':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'editable medium-editor-textarea'})
        }
```

MODELS.PY CODES:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse,reverse_lazy
# Create your models here.

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def approve_comments(self):
        return self.comments.filter(approve_comment=True)

    def get_absolute_rul(self):
        return reverse("post_detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('blog.Post',related_name='comments',on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    approve_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def approve(self):
        self.approved_comment = True
        self.save()

    def get_absolute_rul(self):
        return reverse('post_list')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

URLS.PY (in the same folder that setting.py is in):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib.auth import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'',include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'accounts/login/$',views.LoginView,name='login'),
    url(r'accounts/logout/$',views.LogoutView,name='logout',kwargs={'next_page':'/'}),

]
```

URLS.PY (in the same folder that VIEWS.PY is in)

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from blog import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.PostListView.as_view(),name='post_list'),
    url(r'^about/$',views.AboutView.as_view(),name='about'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)$',views.PostDetailView.as_view(),name='post_detail'),
    url(r'^post/new/$',views.CreatePostView.as_view(),name='post_new'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$',views.PostUpdateView.as_view(),name='post_edit'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/remove/$',views.PostDetailView.as_view(),name='post_remove'),
    url(r'^drafts/$',views.DraftListView.as_view(),name='post_draft_list'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/comment/$',views.add_comment_to_post,name='add_comment_to_post'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/approve/$',views.comment_approve,name='comment_approve'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/remove/$',views.comment_remove,name='comment_remove'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/publish/$',views.post_publish,name='post_publish'),

]
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Please show urls.py

Comment: urls.py added to the end of the post

Comment: @sf31 the problem is with`LoginView` and `LogoutView `in the **urls.py**. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your urls, you are not using [as_view()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view) at the end of [class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/). You need to use it like this:

```
path('about/', AboutView.as_view(), name='about')
```

#### Update

Problem is in your `LoginView` and `LogoutView` which is imported from `django.contrib.auth.views`. They are class Based Views. So you need to add `as_view` at the end of them when declaring in the class.

```
url(r'accounts/login/$',views.LoginView.as_view(),name='login'),
url(r'accounts/logout/$',views.LogoutView.as_view(),name='logout',kwargs={'next_page':'/'})
```